How to assure the execution order when running the full code?
I want to mark the whole code in R Studio and run it instead of execute every single line of code one by one. But it appears that some arguments are executed before others that appear in the Syntax before. As a result, some objects are not found that are referred to in an argument because the line of code was executed before the line in which the object is defined.
How can I avoid this and still not have to run every single line manually?
Thanks a lot!

The behaviour you are describing is inconsistent with what RStudio actually does: if you highlight a block of code and execute that, it is executed in proper order, contrary to what you seem to assume. In other words: what you want works as-is. If it doesn’t, you’re doing something else wrong.

In RStudio, you can click the "Source" icon on the top right, just above your active code, to run the active script in entirety. You may want to remove objects from your Environment / restart R to be sure that your code is not using stale data.
